# what exactly is `xla_client` in the jax library?

Tags: tensorflow, jax

If you read the [jax source code](https://github.com/google/jax) you'll hit something called `xla_client`. Often imported like this

```
from . import xla_client
```

This implies that `xla_client` is a python module, but I can't find any file with that name or reference to a variable of that name.

I assume that it is related to https://pypi.org/project/jaxlib/, but this package just links back to the jax source code.

Can anybody clue me in?

Answer (score 5):

The file you're referring to is stored at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/compiler/xla/python

Let me expound further: `xla_client` is partly a wrapper around a specially compiled c++ file called `xla_extension.so`, for example see

```
from . import xla_extension as _xla
```

and numerous references to `_xla` throughout `xla_config`. The source for this file is https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/compiler/xla/python/xla.cc, which we know because it says so quite clearly in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/compiler/xla/python/BUILD

```
pybind_extension(
name = "xla_extension",
srcs = [
    "xla.cc",
],
...
```